Decrypt & Re-Encrypt Chrome cookies
I'm trying to decrypt Chrome's cookie SQLite DB, and move the decrypted cookies to another computer (browser), and re-encrypt the DB, and replicate sessions.
Here is what I plan:

Decrypt AES key from Local State in C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State using DPAPI
Use decrypted key to decrypt Cookie DB in C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network\Cookies
Copy the decrypted Cookie DB to another computer
Generate random AES key/nonce and encrypt the plaintext Cookie DB transferred on the other computer. Substitute original Cookies DB on the other computer.
Encrypt AES key using DPAPI and substitute associated entry in Local State on the other computer.

And I have the following 2 Python files to do things described above:
encrypt.py:
from win32.win32crypt import CryptProtectData
import base64
import sqlite3
import os
from Cryptodome.Cipher.AES import new, MODE_GCM # pip install pycryptodomex
import decrypt
import json

def encrypt_dpapi_blob(decrypted_blob):
    encrypted_blob = CryptProtectData(decrypted_blob, DataDescr="Google Chrome", OptionalEntropy=None, Reserved=None, PromptStruct=None, Flags=0)
    encrypted_blob = b'DPAPI' + encrypted_blob
    encrypted_blob_base64 = base64.b64encode(encrypted_blob)
    return encrypted_blob_base64

def encrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key):
    sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)

    query = "SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
    query_res = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in query_res:
        cookie_name, decrypted_value = row
        # print(f"Encrypting cookie: {cookie_name}")
        if decrypted_value is None or len(decrypted_value) == 0:
            # print("No decrypted value found.")
            continue

        aes_cipher = new(key=key, mode=MODE_GCM, nonce=decrypted_value[3:15])
        encrypted_value = aes_cipher.encrypt(decrypted_value[15: -16])
        # print(f"Encrypted cookie:\n  {decrypt.bytes_to_hex(encrypted_value)}\n  {encrypted_value}")

        verification_tag = decrypted_value[-16:]
        # print(f"Verification tag:\n  {decrypt.bytes_to_hex(verification_tag)}\n  {verification_tag}")

        nonce = decrypted_value[3:15]
        # print(f"Nonce:\n  {decrypt.bytes_to_hex(nonce)}\n  {nonce}")

        encrypted_cookie = b'\x76\x31\x30' +\
            nonce +\
            encrypted_value +\
            verification_tag

        query = f"UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE name = \"{cookie_name}\""
        params = [encrypted_cookie]
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        # print("")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cookies_db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Cookies")
    # print(f"Decrypted key:\n  {decrypt.bytes_to_hex(key)}\n  {key}")

    key = os.urandom(32)
    encrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key)
    encrypted_key = encrypt_dpapi_blob(key)
    print(f"Encrypted key:\n  {str(encrypted_key, 'utf-8')}")

    local_state = json.load(open('Local State'))
    local_state['os_crypt']['encrypted_key'] = encrypted_key.decode()
    json.dump(local_state, open('Local State', 'w'))


decrypt.py:
from win32.win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData
import base64
import sqlite3
import os
from Cryptodome.Cipher.AES import new, MODE_GCM # pip install pycryptodomex
import sys
import json


def decrypt_dpapi_blob(encrypted_blob):
    encrypted_blob = base64.b64decode(encrypted_blob)[5:]  # Leading bytes "DPAPI" need to be removed
    decrypt_res = CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_blob, None, None, None, 0)
    return decrypt_res

def decrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key):
    sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)

    query = "SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
    query_res = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in query_res:
        cookie_name, encrypted_value = row
        # print(f"Decrypting cookie: {cookie_name}")
        if encrypted_value is None or len(encrypted_value) == 0:
            # print("No encrypted value found.")
            continue

        aes_cipher = new(key=key, mode=MODE_GCM, nonce=encrypted_value[3:15])
        decrypted_value = aes_cipher.decrypt(encrypted_value[15: -16])
        # print(f"Decrypted cookie:\n  {bytes_to_hex(decrypted_value)}\n  {decrypted_value}")
        if cookie_name == "BITBUCKETSESSIONID":
            print(f"Decrypted cookie (bitbucket): {decrypted_value.decode()}")

        verification_tag = encrypted_value[-16:]
        # print(f"Verification tag:\n  {bytes_to_hex(verification_tag)}\n  {verification_tag}")

        nonce = encrypted_value[3:15]
        # print(f"Nonce:\n  {bytes_to_hex(nonce)}\n  {nonce}")

        decrypted_cookie = b'\x76\x31\x30' +\
            nonce +\
            decrypted_value +\
            verification_tag

        query = f"UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE name = \"{cookie_name}\""
        params = [decrypted_cookie]
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        # print("")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def bytes_to_hex(byte_data):
    return f"b'{''.join(f'\\x{byte:02x}' for byte in byte_data)}'"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    encrypted_key_base64 = json.load(open('Local State'))['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']

    # print(f"Encrypted key:\n  {encrypted_key_base64}")
    try:
        decrypted_key = decrypt_dpapi_blob(encrypted_key_base64)[1]
        print(f"Decrypted key:\n  {bytes_to_hex(decrypted_key)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Decryption failed:", str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    
    # get current working directory path
    cookies_db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Cookies")
    decrypt_cookies(cookies_db, decrypted_key)
    # print(f"Decrypted key:\n  {bytes_to_hex(decrypted_key)}")


With these functions, I can get the plaintext cookie and verified that, if I manually copy the cookie text in Chrome, I can get the target session.
if cookie_name == "BITBUCKETSESSIONID":
            print(f"Decrypted cookie (bitbucket): {decrypted_value.decode()}")

Decrypting & Encrypting back and forth work without problem as well.
However, if I substitute the modified Cookies file and Local State file, Chrome will not read the migrated cookie.
May I know what is wrong here?

As suggested by Topaco in the comments, I modified my functions in the following ways:

Using existing local AES key on the other computer
Generate new random nonce (nonce = os.urandom(12))
Change encrypt to encrypt_and_digest, and decrypt to decrypt_and_verify
Store new verification tag returned by encrypt_and_digest & nonce in encrypted_cookie

... and here are the new functions:
encrypt.py:
from win32.win32crypt import CryptProtectData
import base64
import sqlite3
import os
from Cryptodome.Cipher.AES import new, MODE_GCM # pip install pycryptodomex
import decrypt
import json
from os.path import expandvars

def encrypt_dpapi_blob(decrypted_blob):
    encrypted_blob = CryptProtectData(decrypted_blob, DataDescr="Google Chrome", OptionalEntropy=None, Reserved=None, PromptStruct=None, Flags=0)
    encrypted_blob = b'DPAPI' + encrypted_blob
    encrypted_blob_base64 = base64.b64encode(encrypted_blob)
    return encrypted_blob_base64

def encrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key):
    sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)

    query = "SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
    query_res = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in query_res:
        cookie_name, decrypted_value = row
        # print(f"Encrypting cookie: {cookie_name}")
        if decrypted_value is None or len(decrypted_value) == 0:
            # print("No decrypted value found.")
            continue
        
        nonce = os.urandom(12)

        aes_cipher = new(key=key, mode=MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
        # encrypted_value = aes_cipher.encrypt(decrypted_value[15: -16]) # wrong
        encrypted_value, verification_tag = aes_cipher.encrypt_and_digest(decrypted_value[15: -16])
        # print(f"Encrypted cookie:\n  {decrypt.bytes_to_hex(encrypted_value)}\n  {encrypted_value}")

        # verification_tag = decrypted_value[-16:] # wrong
        # print(f"Verification tag:\n  {decrypt.bytes_to_hex(verification_tag)}\n  {verification_tag}")

        # nonce = decrypted_value[3:15] # wrong
        # print(f"Nonce:\n  {decrypt.bytes_to_hex(nonce)}\n  {nonce}")

        encrypted_cookie = b'\x76\x31\x30' +\
            nonce +\
            encrypted_value +\
            verification_tag

        query = f"UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE name = \"{cookie_name}\""
        params = [encrypted_cookie]
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        # print("")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def get_local_state_key():
    local_state = json.load(open(expandvars('%LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Local State')))
    encrypted_key = local_state['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']
    decrypted_key = decrypt.decrypt_dpapi_blob(encrypted_key)[1]
    return decrypted_key

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cookies_db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Cookies")
    # print(f"Decrypted key:\n  {decrypt.bytes_to_hex(key)}\n  {key}")

    # key = os.urandom(32)
    # Using existing key
    key = get_local_state_key()
    encrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key)
    # encrypted_key = encrypt_dpapi_blob(key)
    # print(f"Encrypted key:\n  {str(encrypted_key, 'utf-8')}")

    # wrong
    # local_state = json.load(open('Local State'))
    # local_state['os_crypt']['encrypted_key'] = encrypted_key.decode()
    # json.dump(local_state, open('Local State', 'w'))

decrypt.py:
from win32.win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData
import base64
import sqlite3
import os
from Cryptodome.Cipher.AES import new, MODE_GCM # pip install pycryptodomex
import sys
import json
import encrypt

def decrypt_dpapi_blob(encrypted_blob):
    encrypted_blob = base64.b64decode(encrypted_blob)[5:]  # Leading bytes "DPAPI" need to be removed
    decrypt_res = CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_blob, None, None, None, 0)
    return decrypt_res

def decrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key):
    sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)

    query = "SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
    query_res = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in query_res:
        cookie_name, encrypted_value = row
        # print(f"Decrypting cookie: {cookie_name}")
        if encrypted_value is None or len(encrypted_value) == 0:
            # print("No encrypted value found.")
            continue

        aes_cipher = new(key=key, mode=MODE_GCM, nonce=encrypted_value[3:15])
        # decrypted_value = aes_cipher.decrypt(encrypted_value[15: -16]) # wrong
        decrypted_value = aes_cipher.decrypt_and_verify(encrypted_value[15: -16], encrypted_value[-16:])
        # print(f"Decrypted cookie:\n  {bytes_to_hex(decrypted_value)}\n  {decrypted_value}")
        if cookie_name == "BITBUCKETSESSIONID":
            print(f"Decrypted cookie (bitbucket): {decrypted_value.decode()}")

        verification_tag = encrypted_value[-16:]
        # print(f"Verification tag:\n  {bytes_to_hex(verification_tag)}\n  {verification_tag}")

        nonce = encrypted_value[3:15]
        # print(f"Nonce:\n  {bytes_to_hex(nonce)}\n  {nonce}")

        decrypted_cookie = b'\x76\x31\x30' +\
            nonce +\
            decrypted_value +\
            verification_tag

        query = f"UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE name = \"{cookie_name}\""
        params = [decrypted_cookie]
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        # print("")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

# Custom function to display all bytes in the \x[something] format
def bytes_to_hex(byte_data):
    return f"b'{''.join(f'\\x{byte:02x}' for byte in byte_data)}'"

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # encrypted_key_base64 = json.load(open('Local State'))['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']

    # print(f"Encrypted key:\n  {encrypted_key_base64}")
    try:
        decrypted_key = encrypt.get_local_state_key()
        print(f"Decrypted key:\n  {bytes_to_hex(decrypted_key)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Decryption failed:", str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    
    # get current working directory path
    cookies_db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Cookies")
    decrypt_cookies(cookies_db, decrypted_key)
    # print(f"Decrypted key:\n  {bytes_to_hex(decrypted_key)}")


When encrypting, you use a new key, but seem to store the old tag along with the new ciphertext. This is wrong. The new key changes the tag and you must store the new tag, otherwise authentication will fail during decryption.

Regarding the nonce: It is not required to use the old nonce, a new random 12 bytes nonce per encryption could also be applied. Regarding the master key: You could also use the existing master key of the target computer, a new master key does not have to be created (but you may have other reasons for a new master key).

Note that you are using unsuitable PyCryptodome functions for GCM, the correct ones for encryption are encrypt_and_digest() (returns ciphertext and tag) and for authentication/decryption decrypt_and_verify() (expects ciphertext and tag). In contrast, encrypt() does not generate a tag and decrypt() does not authenticate.

@Topaco Thank you very much for your corrections! I modified the two files as suggested (see updated question), and I can: 1) encrypt/decrypt Cookies on this computer 2) re-encrypt Cookies on the other computer. However, when I tried to re-decrypt Cookies on the other computer, it will return MAC check failed error. May I know why is it so this time?

To be specific: De/encrypt on the same computer works fine, but decrypt (computer 1) -> encrypt (computer 2) -> [decrypt (computer 2)] do not work. The last step will fail.

OK. I noticed that only 1 of the cookies' re-decryption will fail... magically.

As suggested by Topaco in the comments, and according to my own attempts I modified my functions in the following ways:

Using existing local AES key on the other computer
Generate new random nonce (nonce = os.urandom(12))
Change encrypt to encrypt_and_digest, and decrypt to decrypt_and_verify
Store new verification tag returned by encrypt_and_digest & nonce in encrypted_cookie
Substitute double quotes by single quotes in SQL query
... and here are the new functions:

encrypt.py:
import argparse
import json
import os
import base64
import sqlite3
from os.path import expandvars

from Cryptodome.Cipher.AES import new, MODE_GCM # pip install pycryptodomex
from win32.win32crypt import CryptProtectData # pip install pywin32

import decrypt


def encrypt_dpapi_blob(decrypted_blob):
    encrypted_blob = CryptProtectData(decrypted_blob, DataDescr="Google Chrome", OptionalEntropy=None, Reserved=None, PromptStruct=None, Flags=0)
    encrypted_blob = b'DPAPI' + encrypted_blob
    encrypted_blob_base64 = base64.b64encode(encrypted_blob)
    return encrypted_blob_base64


def encrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key):
    sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)

    query = "SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
    query_res = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in query_res:
        cookie_name, decrypted_value = row
        if decrypted_value is None or len(decrypted_value) == 0:
            continue
        
        nonce = os.urandom(12)
        aes_cipher = new(key=key, mode=MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
        encrypted_value, verification_tag = aes_cipher.encrypt_and_digest(decrypted_value)

        encrypted_cookie = b'\x76\x31\x30' +\
            nonce +\
            encrypted_value +\
            verification_tag

        query = f"UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE name = '{cookie_name}'"
        params = [encrypted_cookie]
        cursor.execute(query, params)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def get_local_state_key():
    local_state = json.load(open(expandvars('%LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Local State')))
    encrypted_key = local_state['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']
    decrypted_key = decrypt.decrypt_dpapi_blob(encrypted_key)[1]
    return decrypted_key


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Arg: cookies_db
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--cookies", help="Name of the cookies database file", default="Cookies")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    cookies_db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), args.cookies)
    key = get_local_state_key()
    encrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key)

decrypt.py:
import argparse
import base64
import os
import sqlite3
import sys

from Cryptodome.Cipher.AES import new, MODE_GCM # pip install pycryptodomex
from win32.win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData # pip install pywin32

import encrypt


def decrypt_dpapi_blob(encrypted_blob):
    encrypted_blob = base64.b64decode(encrypted_blob)[5:]  # Leading bytes "DPAPI" need to be removed
    decrypt_res = CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_blob, None, None, None, 0)
    return decrypt_res


def decrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key):
    sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)

    query = "SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
    query_res = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in query_res:
        cookie_name, encrypted_value = row
        if encrypted_value is None or len(encrypted_value) == 0:
            continue

        verification_tag = encrypted_value[-16:]
        aes_cipher = new(key=key, mode=MODE_GCM, nonce=encrypted_value[3:15])
        decrypted_value = aes_cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext=encrypted_value[15: -16], received_mac_tag=verification_tag)
        # if cookie_name == "BITBUCKETSESSIONID":
        #     print(f"Decrypted cookie (bitbucket):\n  {decrypted_value.decode()}")
        #     print(f"Verification tag (bitbucket):\n  {bytes_to_hex(verification_tag)}")
        #     print(f"Nonce (bitbucket):\n  {bytes_to_hex(nonce)}")
        query = f"UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE name = '{cookie_name}'"
        params = [decrypted_value]
        cursor.execute(query, params)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        decrypted_key = encrypt.get_local_state_key()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Decryption failed:", str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    
    # Arg: cookies_db
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--cookies", help="Name of the cookies database file", default="Cookies")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    cookies_db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), args.cookies)

    decrypt_cookies(cookies_db, decrypted_key)

And now these functions can be used to migrate cookies between computers without error.
